# Solve within a range?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to solve an equation in which some some of the parameters have defined ranges?

Example:

```
Solve[x^2 + 0.09149 x + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 x + 0.9574) == 0 && 
      y^2 + 0.09149 y + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 y + 0.9574) == 0 && 
      kp (10.95 z + 0.9574) == 0, {kp}]
```

where `x < -4` and `y < -5` and `0 > z > -5`.

I am trying to solve for variable `kp` and would like to know how the value of `kp` differs for different values of x, y and z which is defined. X and y shall of course have some kind of max value for which it shall evaluate the solve function.

Ohh.. one important fact.  Kp can't become negative.  it's the main reason why i want to to solve it for for changing parameter defined within a range.

Comment: No, expressions cannot be solved but equations sometimes...

Comment: To make this question answerable, you should add example code to detail your problem.

Comment: I tried to make it more understandable??

Comment: Not completely sure about the last paragraph, but perhaps the example will help to get an idea of what you are after.

Comment: It's an optimization question, more or less. Please reopen.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
Clear[x,y,z,kp];
Reduce[FullSimplify[
x < -4 && y < -5 && 0 > z > -5 && 
x^2 + 0.09149 x + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 x + 0.9574) == 0 && 
y^2 + 0.09149 y + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 y + 0.9574) == 0 && 
kp (10.95 z + 0.9574) == 0], {x, y, z, kp}]
```

to get:

```
x < -5. && y == x && z == -0.0874338 && 
kp == (-6263. - 9.149*10^7 x - 1.*10^9 x^2)/
(9.574*10^8 + 1.095*10^10 x)
```

and a plot:
[image: Plot]

**Edit** when `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify` is used, we get a different `kp`:

```
x < -5. && y == x && z == -0.0874338 && 
kp == (-9.09542*10^15 - 1.32866*10^20 x - 1.45225*10^21 x^2)/(
1.39038*10^21 + 1.59021*10^22 x)
```

and the plot has a slightly different slope.

Comment: Ohh.. one important fact. Kp can't become negative. it's the main reason why i want to to solve it for for changing parameter defined within a range.

Comment: But your solution seems to make it work..How did get the equation for kp, i have mutiple equations  which i need this operation to be done.. so a method would be helpfull, your reduce function doesn't seem to give me the equation.

Comment: But those have multiple variables (kp,ki,kd) which I need to adjust for..  but using your method it looks like i am getting a function for ki which is dependent of kp, kp,ki and kd, shall only depend of the values of x,y and z.

Comment: @ssolver, I took your statement and added the conditions from the 'Where' and did the `Reduce[FullSimplify` which gave us the next box.  The part to the right of `kp==` is what I plotted.

Comment: Hmm.. but i don't get any of these equation. it just evalutates the box, but doesn't give any output..

Comment: @ssolver, perhaps you need `Clear[x,y,z,kp]`. Copy the first statement and remove `Full` and evaluate and you should get my edit result.

Comment: Ahh.. that works.. But now i am having problems solving them for multiple parameters..  I am only one equation where one parameter depend on the other one.

Comment: @ssolver, for example: `(your dependency here) &&` at the beginning of the statement. good luck!

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with this approach, because i am not getting the values i should get...

Answer (score 5):

You can get the range of values by minimizing and maximizing `kp` with the specified constraints. Since the input is approximate `Minimize` will punt to `NMinimize` so what you see below is not a guaranteed result. All the same one can get a good idea of which bounds are tight and what is the range in question.

```
Minimize[{kp, 
  x^2 + 0.09149 x + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 x + 0.9574) == 0, 
  y^2 + 0.09149 y + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 y + 0.9574) == 0, 
  kp (10.95 z + 0.9574) == 0, x <= -4, y <= -5, 0 > z > -5}, {kp, x, 
  y, z}]

During evaluation of In[40]:= NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

(* Out[40]= {0.456244070108, {kp -> 0.456244070108, x -> -4.99999977222, 
  y -> -5., z -> -0.0874337974049}} *)

Maximize[{kp, 
  x^2 + 0.09149 x + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 x + 0.9574) == 0, 
  y^2 + 0.09149 y + 6.263*10^-6 + kp (10.95 y + 0.9574) == 0, 
  kp (10.95 z + 0.9574) == 0, x <= -4, y <= -5, 0 > z > -5}, {kp, x, 
  y, z}]

(* Out[41]= {6811.46425441, {kp -> 6811.46425441, x -> -74585.537642, 
  y -> -74585.537642, z -> -0.0874337899543}} *)
```

Comment: it's not possible to get values from within the range, just from it's max. and min. range values.

Comment: Ohh.. one important fact. Kp can't become negative. it's the main reason why i want to to solve it for for changing parameter defined within a range.

Comment: The other constraints already prevent it from becoming negative. Per computations above, it ranges from 0.456... to 6811.464...